# Where does geth stores SNAPSHOT data

Tags: geth

A new sync mode called "snapshot"  was implemented in geth v1.10. It requires 35+Gib space to store data. I can't find the folder where snapshot data stored. My purpose Is to redirect docker geth container folders to persistent volumes, i want to have separate archive folder location (on HDD), chaindata (slow ssd) and snapshot (maybe fast NVME PCI-E) folders to speed up my node and optimize disk usage. In that case, i can't just redirect /root to persistence volume, and my questions are:

- where geth stores snapshot data?
- maybe linux gurus can tell me, if i can redirect whole /root folder to ssd, and somehove re-redirect archive folder to /hdd (without mapping subfolders in docker)